# Setting background image URL in SafeHtmlTemplates

Tags: gwt

I have the following code in which I want to create a `div` with a dynamic background:

```
public interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<div class='imageDiv' style=\"background-image: url({0});\"/>")
    SafeHtml content(String picture);
}

public void render(SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder, final T model) {
    SafeHtml html = TEMPLATE.content(picture);
    safeHtmlBuilder.append(html);
}
```

After running the app, first I had this warning :

```
Template with variable in CSS attribute context: 
The template code generator cannot guarantee HTML-safety of the template
```

Then an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(SafeHtmlUtils.java:156)
at xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.ImageItemCell_TemplateImpl.content(ImageItemCell_TemplateImpl.java:14)
at xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.ImageItemCell.render(ImageItemCell.java:53)
```

---

When I try setting the picture as SafeUri:

```
SafeUri uri = UriUtils.fromTrustedString(picture);
SafeHtml html = TEMPLATE.content(uri);
```

I get this different error:

```
 [ERROR] - SafeUri can only be used as the entire value of a URL attribute. 
          Did you mean to use java.lang.String or SafeHtml instead?
```

What should I do in this case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SafeStyles`:

```
public interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<div class='imageDiv' style='{0}'></div>")
    SafeHtml content(SafeStyles picture);
}

public void render(SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder, final T model) {
    SafeHtml html = TEMPLATE.content(SafeStyleUtils.forBackgroundImage(picture));
    safeHtmlBuilder.append(html);
}
```

(assuming `picture` is a `SafeUri` here)

Comment: thank you for your reply, how about if there are other elements in the style like width and height ? what's the syntax?

Comment: You'd then use `SafeStylesBuilder`